# Complex number, exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all values of $z$ such that

i) $e^z=-2$

ii) $e^z=1+i\sqrt{3}$

iii) $e^{2z-1}=1$

What I did

I know that $e^z=e^x(cosy+iseny)$, then

i) $e^x\geq0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ so I need to find $y$ such that $cosy=-1$ and $seny=0$, so $y=n\pi$ for $n=1,3,5...$ and $e^x=2\rightarrow x=log(2)$ so $z=log(2)+n\pi$, that is right?

If anyone can make the step by step solution in polar form I thank

Comment: Do you know that the expontential is $2\pi i$-periodic?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I know

Comment: Then I suggest you write the RHSs in their polar form.

Comment: @GitGud My idea is wrong?

Comment: The idea is OK, but I didn't if it's actually right.

Comment: Hint: -2 = 2e^(ipi) = e^(ln(2))e^(ipi)


E: I suck at formatting

Comment: @GitGud You can make the answer in polar form? I was looking at my notes and I could not see difference

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD How can I write $e^z$ in polar form?